# Looking or an autocomplete filename vscode plugin

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any VSC plugin that allow to autocomplete file path within a project folder? I am used to RStudio, where I could simply start typing the name of a file, hit tab, and then rapidly find the corresponding file (see below).

[image]

I have tried *Path Autocomplete* and *Path Intelisense*, but could not get them working like this.

Thank you,
Phil

Comment: what happens when you use `Ctrl+Space` or `Ctrl+Shift+Space` when you have typed a few characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using the [RelativePath](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jakob101.RelativePath) extention by jakob101 for the past couple of years.

It searches for files within the workspace and pastes a relative path at the cursor.
Super simple and easy to use.

Comment: Oh, that looks good. Any way to remove the leading dots in the file name? So this `read.csv("data/raw/myfile.csv")` is used instead of `read.csv("../data/raw/myfile.csv")`. I looked in the settings but could not find how.

Comment: I found it by modifying `relativePath.omitParts`.